# redundant relations

Tags: gr.group-theory

The situation is the following: I have a group of matrices (given by generators), and I am trying to find a presentation. Now, this is in general very hard (undecidable?) but here I want to know if people know heuristics for pruning the set of relators -- in other words, by computing further generations of the group, I get a number of words $w_1, \dots, w_k$ which represent the identity. No doubt some of these relations are consequences of others, so is there some nice way to remove the "dependent relations"?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a hard problem. For example, even if your generating matrices are only $2 \times 2$ and with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$, there is no bound $B$ such that if you don't find a relation of length $\leq B$, your group is free -- cf. Mark Sapir's answer to the following question of mine: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119879/free-subgroups-of-gl2-z.

Comment: @StefanKohl I agree that the general recognition of group question is very hard (as I say, most likely undecidable in general), but the question I ask is much easier (at least so it would seem).

Comment: Over which domain(s) are your matrices, i.e. in which ring are the entries?

Comment: @StephanKohl The matrices are over $\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: I would guess the best heuristics involve look at images under well chosen congruence subgroups.

Comment: Do you assume beforehand that your group is finitely presentable? Lots of f.g. matrix groups over $\mathbf{Z}$ are not finitely presentable. I don't know if it's decidable whether 2 matrices in a given $SL_n(\mathbf{Z})$ generate a f.p. group.

Comment: @YvesCornulier are there explicit non f.p. examples?

Comment: Yes: in $SL_4(\mathbf{Z})$ you have an explicit direct product of 2 free groups. If $F$ is freely generated by $x,y$, and $p$ is the projection from $F$ to the cyclic group killing $y$, then let $P$ be the fibre product consisting of pairs $(u,v)$ such that $p(x)=p(y)$. Then $P$ is generated by $(x,x)$, $(y,y)$ and $(1,y)$. It's well-known to be not finitely presented, see the references in Bridson's papers.

Comment: @YvesCornulier, actually, I now realise that finite presentability *is* now known to be undecidable for 2-generator matrix groups.  Rips' original construction gives 2-generator subgroups of C'(1/6) groups, and by Agol, Haglund and Wise's theorems, they are in fact $\mathbb{Z}$-linear (and one can compute the corresponding matrices).

Comment: (On the other hand, it's conceivable that it's decidable in $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ for any fixed $n$, though I can't say I think this is very likely.)

Comment: @HJRW: Haglund-Wise is enough: they constructed a Rips machine with subgroups of right-angled Artin groups. Actually it now follows from Agol's later paper that Rips' original construction already provides subgroups of right-angled Artin groups.

Comment: @YvesCornulier - no, not for 2-generator subgroups: the number of generators of the kernel in Haglund--Wise's construction depends on the input. You need to use Rips' original construction, and hence also invoke Agol's result.

Answer (score 11):

This doesn't answer the main question, but it does address the parenthetical question of the decidability of computing presentations in matrix groups. In so doing, I hope it helps to clarify Joel and Benjamin's answers.

Bridson and I showed that the problem of computing presentations in matrix groups over $\mathbb{Z}$ is undecidable, in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5117) paper.  More precisely, we produce a recursive sequence of subsets $S_n\subseteq SL_{m_n}(\mathbb{Z})$ and an r.e. sequence of integers $r_n$ such that:

- for each $n$, $\langle S_n\rangle$ is finitely presentable (in principle!), but
- the set
  $\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid b_1(\langle S_n\rangle)=r_n\}$
  is r.e. but not recursive.

So $b_1(\langle S_n\rangle)$ (the first Betti number) is not computable. Since it's straightforward to compute $b_1$ from a presentation, it follows that presentations are not computable.

Unfortunately, in our examples, $m_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. It would be great to have examples in which $m_n$ was bounded (and even better to have examples in which $m_n=3$).

Answer (score 7):

Let's ignore the source of the group, and concentrate on the question you seem to be asking. Let $G = \langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_r \mid r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_s \rangle$ be a finite group presentation, where the $r_i$ are defining relators. Can we decide whether $r_s$ is redundant; that is, whether $G = \langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_r \mid r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_{s-1} \rangle$.

As others have pointed out, the theoretical answer is no, but the problem is a semi-decidable probelm in the sense that, if the answer is yes, then you can prove constructively that it is yes. In practice there are two well studied and implemented algorithms that you can use to try and do this.

The first is Todd-Coxeter coset enumeration, which is most useful when the groups are finite, so that is probably not the best choice here.

The second is Knuth-Bendix completion, and that is the most likely to be useful here. You run it on the presentation $\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_r \mid r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_{s-1} \rangle$. It will probably not halt, but that doesn't matter. Just run it for a few minutes or a few days, or whatever. Then interrupt it (or wait until it exceeds some bound - I usually tell it stop when it has produced a million rewrite rules or something). Then you can quickly check whether $r_s$ reduces to the identity under the rewrite rules that you have generated. If $r_s$ really is a consequence of the other relators, then you know that this method will work if you run the program for long eneough but, except in the rare cases when the process completes with a confluent presentation, you cannot use this method to prove the answer is no.

The only practical ways of showing that $r_s$ is not a consequence of the other relators is to compute some of the quotients of $G$ and see if you get different results by leaving out $r_s$. There are algorithms available for computing finite quotients, virtually abelian quotients, virtually nilpotent quoteints, etc.

Knuth-Bendix completion and the quotient algorithms are available in both GAP and Magma.

Answer (score 6):

This should be a comment but is too long. The decidability of the question whether a finite set R of relations implies some other relation r=1 in all linear groups is the same as asking if R implies r=1 in all finite groups because of Malcev's theorem on residual finiteness of linear groups. A beautiful theorem of Slobodoskoii says this latter problem is undecidable.

A consequence is that the first order theory for finite dimensional modules over an algebra of wild representation type is undecidable. (Most books on finite dimensional algebras mistakenly assert it follows from undecidability of the word problem for groups, but one must then allow infinite dimensional modules.)

**Edit.** The question is not entirely well posed. It is impossible to decide whether your group is finitely presented as @HJRW points out. @IgorRivkin says he wants to know how to prune relations, that is, given a finite set of relations that are true remove others that are consequence. The ambiguity is whether one means redundant in a linear group or in all groups. If one means in all groups, then the fact that your group is linear seems a red herring and you are in the situation that @JoelHamkins and @DerekHolt give in their answers. My answer was assuming that you want to know if certain relations were consequences of others in all linear groups. If this is what you want the best semi-procedure is to look at images under congruence homomorphisms to rule out certain relations as being redundant and follow Derek's procedure to say that certain relations are redundant.

Comment: I wasn't really intending to suggest that the source of the group was irrelevant (although admittedly what I wrote does imply that!). It is more the case that I did not know how make use of the fact that the group is a matrix group, so I was just offering what limited assitance I could. The other point is that, at the point at which Igor wants to try eliminating relations, he probably does not have a complete presentation of the matrix group in question, so it is not clear that he would be in a position to take advantage of the source.

Comment: @DerekHolt, this is why I am contending the question is ill-posed.  If he wants to exploit having a matrix group he needs to clarify what he knows.  Does he have a complete presentation (perhaps infinite) and wants to remove unnecessary relations? Is he working in the category of linear groups and so wants to remove those relations which are consequences of others in all linear groups? Without more info it is not clear that being linear is relevant.

Answer (score 4):

In the general case, to determine whether some relations imply another given relation is an undecidable problem. If it were decidable, then we could decide whether a given finite presentation was presenting the trivial group or not (a known undecidable problem), by testing whether the generators are all redundant as relations.

Comment: I'm not sure how your context of having matrices affects the situation.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question. The OP already noticed that the general case is hard/undecidable. But I think that the question deals with concrete cases.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I meant only to point out that indeed it is undecidable in the general case, since the comments expressed some degree of uncertainty about this.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, the undecidability with respect to the implications of linear groups is a slightly different problem. Due to residual finiteness checking implications is co-re. I will say more in my answer.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, I'm confused by your comment, since if implication checking is co-re, then it would have to be decidable, since clearly implication checking is also ce by enumerating proofs.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, you cannot enumerate proofs when you restrict the class of groups you are looking at to linear (or finite) groups. We have left the varietal setting.  There are consequences of relations that are true in all linear groups but not all groups. For example let <X|R> be a finite presentation of an infinite simple group. Then R implies x=1 in all linear groups for every x in X because no infinite fg simple group has a non-trivial finite dimensional rep. But of course x=1 is not a consequence of R in all groups so there is no equational proof.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I'm still confused by your comment but I can't tell why. What is the definition of a linear group?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: A group is called 'linear' iff it embeds into ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, that's what I thought. (And I just cleared my confusion, which was mostly due to lack of caffeine.)